# Servlet Thread Sheduling

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

```
public class Authenticate implements Filter
{
static List<Thread> homethread = new ArrayList<Thread>();
static Queue<Thread> threadQueue = new LinkedList<Thread>();
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException 
    {
                if(homethread.size()>=2)
                    {
                     threadQueue.add(Thread.currentThread());
                      while(!threadQueue.isEmpty())
                            {
                        for(Thread th : homethread)
                                {
                                    if(th.getState()!=Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING)
                                    {
                                        homethread.remove(th);
                                        Thread thr = threadQueue.remove();
                                        homethread.add(thr);
                                        chain.doFilter(request, response);
                                    }
                                }
                             }
                    }
                 else
                    {
                            homethread.add(Thread.currentThread());
                            chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    }
    }
```

I've done the above code in a filter to restrict the number of users accessing the servlet (i.e) its a Home Page which Comes after Login

```
public class Home extends HttpServlet 
{
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writter = response.getWriter();
        writter.println
            (
                    "<!DOCTYPE html>" + 
                    "<html>" + 
                    "<body>" +  
                    "<h1 style=\"text-align:center;\">Provide Your Choice</h1>"+
                    "<form action=\"Upload\" method=\"POST\">" +//enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" 
                    "<div style=\"text-align:center\">Upload File     :<input type=\"file\" name=\"UploadedFile\" multiple/><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload\"><br><br>"+
                    "</form>" + 
                    "<div style=\"text-align:center\">View Files     :<input type=\"submit\" formaction=\"View\" formmethod=\"post\" value=\"View\"/><br><br>" + 
                    "<div style=\"text-align:center\"><input type=\"submit\" formaction=\"LogOut\" formmethod=\"post\" value=\"LogOut\"/>" + 
                            "</body>" + 
                            "</html>"
            );
            response.flushBuffer();
            try 
            {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(50000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
   }
}
```

It shows response of Home Page to First 2 users Fine. I've stored the consequent requests(3,4,5) in a queue and i checked if any one of the previous homethreads (1 or 2) Finished its Sleeping State.If it does so then I will remove the awaken thread and pop the 3rd thread (i.e)Head from the queue and let it to do the job (i.e) showing the home page to 3rd user and sleep.
Now as per my moto this is what i Expected.

> 1st User Logs in.
>
> After 10 secs 2nd user Logs in.
>
> After 10 secs 3rd user Logs in and he has to be in wait stage.
>
> After 10 secs 4th user logs in and he has to be in wait stage.
>
> At the time of 50th second 3rd User has to get the response.(i.e)1st User Finished his work.
>
> At the time of 60th second 4th User has to get the response.(i.e)2nd User Finished his work.
>
> But Now the Problem here is both 3rd and 4th user is getting the response at the 50th Second Itself.

Any help will be So much Useful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving your logic aside you need to use thread-safe collections to store threads instead of simple lists. And you can achieve the same result of restricting number of threads that can call filter using `Semaphore` with predefined number of permits.